# Asynchronous JS script is loading with detach browser state

Tags: javascript, html

We are loading user data using `data.js` script trick and would like to detach JS loading from the DOM. It seems `async` script tag loads the script asynchronously but the browser still waits for the script to load and does not fire web page loaded event and shows web page loading progress.

```
  <script async defer importance="high" id="user-data" src="@Url.Action("Data", "User")"></script>
```

I would like to explain the problem that I want to solve. We are hosting our website on CloudFlare and website HTML with assets loaded very fast from CF CDN. The bottleneck is `data.js` which pauses website loading unit it is fully loaded even Async is present on script.

Comment: @Amadan The defer should be ignored because I am on Chrome and both Async and Defer present. The Async always goes first and Defer a fallback. Right?

Comment: You are right, it seems it should.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an 'onload' script that attach your script into DOM after page load.

```
    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
    const deferredScript = document.createElement("script");
        deferredScript.id = 'user-data';
        deferredScript.src = "your-source";
        document.body.appendChild(deferredScript);
    }
    </script>
```